# Security Group changes - Task

Tags: powershell, logging, active-directory, azure-active-directory, scheduled-tasks

I'm currently auditing security events 4728 and 4729 via powershell in order to check group policy changes in a specific domain controller.

The main idea is to check anomalies between a default AD group policy(a "given configuration", for the company group) and the one that changed(from the new snapshot) at the end of the week.

How could I spot differences beetween these two outputs?

I'd use Get-WinEvent -LogName Security, but we can discuss it.

For Changes I refer to these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-security-group-management
(4728,4729 for instance)

I'm looking for a situation like this: an administrator add a user to a security group because the latter has to access a specific file for a short period of time.
Then the admin somehow forgets to restore the original user's configuration policy.

This generates an anomaly, considering the default AD Group Policy.
I have to spot this change from the output.

Now I've wrapped up my rudimentary explination, is there anything you can think of to help with my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are asking for a lot here. This is a project and needed to be approached one step at a time. [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Monitoring ADDS for changes is not a new thing. [monitor active directory changes real time'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27monitor+active+directory+changes+real+time%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Answer (score -1):

The basic command you're looking for would be like this:

```
$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName='Security'; Id=4728, 4729; StartTime=$StartDate }
```

In a script it would be something like this:

```
$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$Results   = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName='Security'; Id=4728, 4729; StartTime=$StartDate }

if ( $Results )
{
    # Send e-mail or something here
}
```

If you want more complex queries you might format it differently.

```
$DaysInThePast = 1
$Hash = @{
    LogName   = 'Security'
    Id        = 4728, 4729
    StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysInThePast)
}

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $Hash
```